# Does $E|X_n|^r\to E|X|^r$ imply $X_n$ converges to $X$ in $r$th mean?

Tags: probability, self-study

If $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables and it converge to $X$ in $r$th mean then we say that $E|X_n-X|^r\to 0$ as $n$ is large. And it also implies that $E|X_n|^r$ goes to $E|X|^r$ for large $n$.

Now is the converse true? That is, if we see that $E|X_n|^r\to E|X|^r$ can we say that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in $r$th mean?

Comment: I think it will be easier to read your question if you use math typesetting. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: See [these notes](https://www.statlect.com/asymptotic-theory/mean-square-convergence) Exercise 2 (proof).

Answer (score 1):

The latter is called moment convergence, and by itself it doesn’t imply the former, called $L_p$ convergence. An easy counterexample is to take $X_n=(-1)^n$, or pretty much any set of random variables not defined on the same space. To guarantee strong convergence you typically also need weak convergence, so if $X_n$ converges to $X$ in distribution, then you can conclude it will also converge strongly.